# Transpose SQL query result in MS ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, transpose

I need help with converting a query result as transpose by month. The table looks like below.
[image]

and I need a result like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional logic to aggregate the results:

```
select sales_person, product, 
       sum(iif(month(sale_date) = 1, selling_price, 0)) as jan,
       sum(iif(month(sale_date) = 2, selling_price, 0)) as feb,
       sum(iif(month(sale_date) = 3, selling_price, 0)) as mar
from t
group by sales_person, product;
```